# ASCII for SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH ORACLE sql

Tags: oracle

Is there any way to use ascii code for value separator in `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`.

For example in `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(columnname,'!')`,

I want to use the ASCII value of `!(33)` instead of actual symbol. Also, can i use the ascii value of `ENTER (13)` as value separator?

Thank you.

Comment: Using `chr(13)` as value separator should work just fine!

Comment: Hello collin,thanks. but when i used SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(column name, chr(33)), it is showing illegal parameter error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`chr` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions026.htm) to replace a character with it's numeric equivalent.

```
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(column name, chr(33))
```

Or to use a line feed, which should also be fine:

```
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(column name, chr(13))
```

It's not strictly ASCII as it depends on your character set, but it will probably work for you. You can see the numeric values using the reverse [`ascii` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions013.htm), which also isn't really quite ASCII, but again close enough especially if you're always using the same character set. So `ascii('!')` would give you `33`.

---

As you've discovered, giving anything except a fixed string literal gives:

> ```
> SQL Error: ORA-30003: illegal parameter in SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH
> function  
> 30003. 00000 -  "illegal parameter in SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function"  
> *Cause:  
> *Action:   use a non-empty constant string as the second argument,
>            then retry the operation.
> ```

This is why I usually test things before posting, but this seemed so simple... You can get around that with `replace`:

```
REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(column name, '/'), '/', chr(33))
```

Borrowing an [example from the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions183.htm):

```
SELECT LPAD(' ', 2*level-1)
      ||replace(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(last_name, '/'),'/',chr(33)) "Path"
   FROM employees
   START WITH last_name = 'Kochhar'
   CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;

Path
--------------------------------------------------
 !Kochhar
   !Kochhar!Greenberg
     !Kochhar!Greenberg!Faviet
     !Kochhar!Greenberg!Chen
     !Kochhar!Greenberg!Sciarra
     !Kochhar!Greenberg!Urman
     !Kochhar!Greenberg!Popp
   !Kochhar!Whalen
   !Kochhar!Mavris
   !Kochhar!Baer
   !Kochhar!Higgins
     !Kochhar!Higgins!Gietz
```

Comment: Hello Alex,thanks for ur comment. but when i used SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(column name, chr(33)), it is showing illegal parameter error

Comment: Hmm, yes, `ORA-30003: illegal parameter in SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function`. Interesting. Why do you want to use the ASCII value instead of a fixed character - are you calling this from somewhere where the `!` (and line feed) is causing a problem?

Comment: Hi all,i found a solution to use ascii in SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH but still it|s not working for Line feed alone. For example,      replace(sys_connect_by_path(ename, '!'), '!', chr(64)) would replace '!' by '@' but replace(sys_connect_by_path(ename, '!'), '!', chr(10 )) is not working.

Comment: I guess you can use a different fixed character, that never appears in the data, and then `replace` that with the `chr(33)`. But it kind of depends why this is an issue. Oh, that's what you came up with, OK. `chr(10)` is new line, not line feed. But maybe your client is just hiding it?

Comment: Hi alex, I mean i want to actually do an enter in place of !.that's the reason i went for chr(10) whichis not working. any idea??

Comment: Why do you think it isn't working - how are you checking the final answer, are you inspecting the string, or displaying it through an IDE, or what? For example it works for me doing this in SQL Developer as a script, but if I run it as a statement (not a script) the grid view of the results makes it look like it's used a space instead of a new line. It hasn't, it's just how its displayed. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Hi Alex, You are absoultely right.  Yes. I got it now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

All the credit goes to Sanjeev Chauhan. Update 7/25/2017: This turned out to be a SQL Developer 4.2.0 and 17.2.0 bug. In SQLPlus and SQL Developer 3.2.2 the statement works fine.
Fix: set secureliterals off;

The source is https://community.oracle.com/thread/4065282

I had changed the version from 4.2.0 to 4.1.1.19 and my piece of code worked. Also be aware that I couldn't find "secureliterals" in version 4.2.0

Comment: I wonder if it's actually a bug. It's present in all SQL Developer versions released in 2020, `set secureliterals off;` doesn't seem to make any change and apparently it also happens in SQL*Plus.